# Laravel DB Facade - is there a maximum rows that can be fetched?

Tags: laravel

When ill try with Laravel:

```
    $bonuses = DB::connection('xxx_old')->table('RechnungBonus')->where('RechnungID','<=',10000)->get();
```

works fine

```
    $bonuses = DB::connection('xxx_old')->table('RechnungBonus')->get();
```

returns null

There are 112000 rows in an that old database - i need to migrate it to a new scheme. Is there a maxium rows number that can be performed by one query? Why its not working when ill try to get ALL rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no technical limit, but your server can easily max out its RAM trying to process so many rows in one go. Laravel provides [chunking](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#chunking-results) to prevent this:

```
DB::connection('xxx_old')->table('RechnungBonus')->chunk(100, function ($bonuses) {
    foreach ($bonuses as $bonus) {
        //
    }
});
```

The above code will process your table in 100 item "chunks", to limit RAM usage. Picking a chunk size is up to you - larger chunks may be a bit faster, but get you closer to maxing out RAM.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But ill have nothing in my log - normally i should get a memory warning, or?

Comment: @derdida If it ran out of RAM, yes. If it didn't, maybe it's just taking a really long time to collect all that data out of the DB. When you do the chunking, try printing out something to the console every 100 rows or so - see if it's progressing properly.

Comment: Thanks again for your explanation!